# AndEngine MultiTouch doesn't work

Tags: java, android, andengine, multi-touch

I am making a simple AndEngine game. It is gonna be commercial so I can't give you my full code but I am doing everything right but MultiTouch doesn't work. I am sure my phone supports multitouchs, it is a Z1. Here what I did:

```
mEngineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);
mScene.setOnAreaTouchTraversalFrontToBack();
mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

Is there anything which I forgot to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you create your EngineOptions properly?
Look at this [example here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/examples/MultiTouchExample.java#L67)

Comment: Yes I create my EngineOptions.